# Javascript code stops working after page Load More .load()

Tags: javascript

When data is fetched on auto Load More, another JavaScript (which is given below) stops working.
Even when it shows the 1st page default it works there but after scrolling down it does not work.

Updated with more explaination with index and getdata file. I'm fetching data like mentioned in the below codes.

**index.php**

```
<div>
<?php include('getdata.php'); ?>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var is_ajaxed = false;
function getresult(url) {
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data:  {rowcount:$("#rowcount").val()+1},
    beforeSend: function(){
    $('#loader-icon').show();
    },
    complete: function(){
    $('#loader-icon').hide();
    },
    success: function(data){
    $("#faq-result").append(data);
    },
    error: function(){} 
    });
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()-900) && is_ajaxed == false){
    if($(".pagenum").val() <= $(".total-page").val()) {
    var pagenum = parseInt($(".pagenum").val()) + 1;
    var pname = "<?php echo $pgianame; ?>";
    var sname = "<?php echo $stianame; ?>";
    getresult('sellers_forum_page_posts_getresult.php?page='+pagenum+'&pname='+pname+'&sname='+sname);
    is_ajaxed = true
    }
    }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**getdata.php**

```
<?php
include ('db.php');

$perPage = 10;

$sql = "select * from posts where status = 1";
$faq3x = $dba3->query($sql);
$allrowscount = mysqli_num_rows($faq3x);
$pages  = ceil($allrowscount/$perPage);

$page = 1;
if(!empty($_GET["page"])) {
$page = $_GET["page"];
}

$start = ($page-1)*$perPage;
if($start <= 0) $start = 0;


$sqlsC = "select * from posts where status = 1 ";
$query =  $sql . " limit " . $start . "," . $perPage; 
$faq3xsC = $dba3->query($query);

echo '<input type="text" class="pagenum" value="'.$page.'" />';
echo '<input type="text" class="total-page" value="'.$pages.'" />';

while ($faqC = $faq3xsC->fetch_assoc()) {

$id =   $faqC['id'];

$ext        =   ".doc";
$name       =   $id.$ext;
$filepath   =   "blog/posts/";

$filename   =   $filepath.$name;

if(file_exists($filename)) {
    if(($fhP = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false ) {
       $headersxP = fread($fhP, 999000);
       $commentsPP  = nl2br($headersxP);
$countxP = 0;
$fhxP = fopen($filename, 'r');
while(!feof($fhxP)){
    $frxP = fread($fhxP, 999999);
    $countxP += strlen($frxP);
}
fclose($fhxP);
?>

<?php echo substr($commentsPP, 0, 511); ?>
<span id="dots_<?php echo $idPost; ?>">...</span>
<span id="more_<?php echo $idPost; ?>" style="">
<?php echo substr($commentsPP, 512, 999999); ?>
</span>
<a onclick="myFunctionx_<?php echo $id; ?>()"
id="myBtn_<?php echo $id; ?>"> See More <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>

<script>
function myFunctionx_<?php echo $id; ?>() {
  var dots_<?php echo $id; ?> = document.getElementById("dots_<?php echo $id; ?>");
  var moreText_<?php echo $id; ?> = document.getElementById("more_<?php echo $id; ?>");
  var btnText_<?php echo $id; ?> = document.getElementById("myBtn_<?php echo $id; ?>");

  if (dots_<?php echo $id; ?>.style.display === "none") {
    dots_<?php echo $id; ?>.style.display = "inline";
    btnText_<?php echo $id; ?>.innerHTML = "&nbsp;See more <i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"; 
    moreText_<?php echo $id; ?>.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots_<?php echo $id; ?>.style.display = "none";
    btnText_<?php echo $id; ?>.innerHTML = "&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i> See less"; 
    moreText_<?php echo $id; ?>.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You never call `myFunctionx`, so its hard to see how this would ever work.

Comment: @Quentin please check now i have updated my question

Comment: Still not a clue. You need a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin please check now i have updated. Or you want a full example with Load More and etc...

Comment: @freedomn-m can you please find a solution for this?